# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n)}{n}$ convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am once again asking about convergence of sums.

1. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n^{(-1)^n})}{n^{p}}, p>0$ converge? As an inexperienced math student, I have not seen this type of function before. It looks to be a changing series, except that it is inside of a ln function. So can I still use the changing series test?
2. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n)}{n}$ converge? Since $-1 \leq \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n) \leq 1$, it looks like I can compare it with $\frac{1}{n}$ and conclude that it diverges too.

Comment: **1)** $\ln(n^{(-1)^n})=(-1)^n\ln(n)$. So, you have an alternating series.  **2)** $\cos(n\pi/2)\in \{-1,1,0\}$, and the series is an alternative series.

Comment: Do not forget: Comparison test works only for nonnegative series.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n)}{n}=\\\frac{0}{1}+\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{0}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{0}{5}+\frac{-1}{6}+\frac{0}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+...\\=-\frac12+\frac14-\frac16+\frac18-\cdots\\=-\frac12(\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots)$$and $\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots$ is wellknown converge series.